# Allocation for UITableViewCell

Tags: cocoa-touch, ipad, uitableview, allocation

Hi guys I've a problem with my project. I've an UIViewController with a UITableView inside. This table loads some custom cell (LSButtonCell).
I've tried to push/pop multiple times this view and I've discovered this strange behavior:
[image: screenshot]
https://i.stack.imgur.com/J0b4D.png
Seems UITableViewCell will not release itself.
What's happened? Any idea?

Comment: Are you sure you want to assign the delegate where you do when returning a reusable cell object? I'd try putting it with the rest of your cell setting code. Also, screenshots of code are easy for you, but no so easy for people to cut and paste your code in to test projects quickly and verify your behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

So far it looks ok, I would make sure that dealloc is called. Try adding NSLog statements in your dealloc methods to see if they are called on screen pop.

Answer (score 0):

There are some issues in your code:

1) You should never retain delegate, only assign. It leads to mutual retaining. So neither of two objects will ever be deallocated.

2) Avoid initiating views with zero rect. For `UIView` `initWithFrame:(CGRect)aFrame` is designated initializer, so aFrame is necessary argument it is easy to guess that necessary argument should not be 0. CGRectZero can play a bad trick on you one day.

3) When you synthesize properties use names for ivars that differs from names of properties, i.e. `@synthesize delegate = delegate_;` so you will never miss calling of setter and getter methods.

Speaking of your problem, it would help if you add header of LSButtonCell to your question.

Comment: I disagree with 2 and 3. With UITableViewCells, the frame of your contentView is not known until layout subviews. I will initialize with CGRectZero and then in layoutSubviews, set the frame accordingly. For 3, I would not call that an issue with the poster's code, rather that is a decision you made for your code. Only in rare cases do I set the property name to be different than the ivar name, usually when I want to make sure I avoid ivar naming collisions in subclasses.

Comment: Sure, it's not obligatory rules. It's just a matter of good style.